# How to dynamically pass parameters in dependency constructors when using DI in typescript

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, typescript-decorator

Prerequisites：

1. npm install 'reflect-metadata'
2. in tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

Let's say you have two Service as follow:

```js
class StoreService {
  constructor(public productIDs:string[]) {}
}

class OrderService {
  constructor(public store: StoreService) {}
}
```

OrderService need StoreService to help itself to do something, you can inject entity of StoreService in entity of OrderService, as follow:

```js
import 'reflect-metadata'

const providers: any[] = []
const instanceMap = new Map()

function Injectable() {
  return function (_constructor: any) {
    providers.push(_constructor)
    return _constructor
  }
}

function hasProvider(dep: any): boolean {
  return providers.includes(dep)
}

@Injectable()
class StoreService {
  constructor(public productIDs: string[]) {}
}

@Injectable()
class OrderService {
  constructor(public store: StoreService) {}
}

function createService(target: any) {
  const Dependencies = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target)
  const args = (Dependencies || []).map((Dep: any) => {
    if (!hasProvider(Dep)) {
      throw new Error(`${Dep.name} has no provider!`)
    }

    const cache = instanceMap.get(Dep)
    if (cache) {
      return cache
    }

    let instance
    if (Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', Dep).length) {
      instance = createService(Dep)
      instanceMap.set(Dep, instance)
    } else {
      instance = new Dep() // can't pass parameters
      instanceMap.set(Dep, instance)
    }
    return instance
  }) as any
  return new target(...args)
}

const order = createService(OrderService)
```

The code above can't run, because when excute '**new Dep()**', the StoreService constructor need a parameter named productIDs, but we don't provide it.

It's a simple example, what I mean is that if the dependency's constructor need to pass parameters, i don't know how to pass them in a generic situation.